# Change PyCharm's settings directory

Tags: pycharm

I'm on `Ubuntu` with the `PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.3`, and I'de like to change its [default locations for settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/directories-used-by-pycharm-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html)

Any environnement variable designed for this purpose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `bin/` directory, there is the **`idea.properties`** file (text format):

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.config.path=${user.home}/.PyCharm/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.system.path=${user.home}/.PyCharm/system

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

You must change the `idea.config.path=${user.home}/.PyCharm/config` line (and uncommet it) and write what you want.

The support is at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-idea-properties.html 
All said `.IntelliJIdea` must be replaced by `.PyCharm`

Comment: Thank you (change `/bin` to `bin/` to not confuse with the system's `/bin`)

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ Not at all.   Fixed it (Now at work, I'm using win).